# double integral for branch function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function f defined by
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}4xy & y\le -x\\2x+y &  y>-x\\\end{cases}

Calculate $$\iint_{R}f(x,y) \operatorname dx \operatorname dy$$
where R = [-2,2] x [0,3].
My difficulty is not knowing how to solve the integral, but knowing which branch of the function to use and the respective limits
Can you help me?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to identify which regions you need to integrate over?

Comment: Change the variables $z=x+y$, $x=x$. Look what the definition of $R$ becomes with new variables. Then integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the inequalities plot of $-2\le x\le 2, 0\le y\le 3, y\le-x$:

[image]

Thus the integral is
$$\int\limits_{-2}^{0} \int\limits_0^{-x} (4xy-2x-y)\, \mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x
+\int\limits_{-2}^{2} \int\limits_0^3 (2x+y)\, \mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x.$$